# Why URI on browser causes socket to run thrice

Tags: java, sockets

This is a simple chat server.
If I run and type : localhost:9092, I get the print statements printing three times each.
I expected them to only print once.
Can someone explain why a just typeing localhost:9092 only once causes while loop to run thrice ?

```
public class ChatServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        PrintWriter pw = null;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9092);
            while (true) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("--- socket properties: " +  socket.getPort());
                pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                pw.println("<font size=\"3\" color=\"red\">This is sme text!</font>");
                pw.println("<font size=\"3\" color=\"green\">This is some text!</font>");
                pw.close();
                socket.close();
                System.out.println("----- someone entered.");
            }
        } finally {
            if (serverSocket != null)
            serverSocket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
--- socket properties: 61802
----- someone entered.
--- socket properties: 61803
----- someone entered.
--- socket properties: 61804
----- someone entered.
```

Comment: Did you type  localhost:9092 in your browser? Maybe the browser sent three times because your server didn't respond with correct HTTP protocol.

Comment: Try the browser console to trace the no. of request send to the server, by pressing `F12` on the browser, goto `Net/Network` tab, then type the url in the address bar and monitor the `net` tab.

Answer (score 2):

You are not responding with the correct HTTP protocol, therefore the client tries 3 times before giving up. HTTP and HTML are NOT the same... do some research on HTTP protocols so that you know what sort of headers and information you need in FRONT of your html so that the client knows what you are talking about.

Answer (score -1):

Try printing out what is being sent to you. You will find it consists of separate GET requests, probably for different resources.